# How to get html text with line break by Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

There is a html text like this:

```
html = '<div class="foo"><span class="bar">text<br>with line break</span></div>'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
```

And I want to get the text `text<br>with line break`.
Currently I'm using

`doc.css("span").to_html.match(/<span .+?>(.*)<\/span>/){ $1 }`

Is there simpler way to make it? If possible I want to avoid using regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the [`inner_html`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#inner_html-instance_method) method?

```
doc.css("span").inner_html
```